# Multple AppyWrenchDialog, storage data structure

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Can you please tell me what is happening when ApplyWrenchDialog is clicked for multiple links.
In which data structure is the name of all those links getting stored. (here by links I mean the links for which apply force/torque dialog is open)

Relevant source code :  gazebo/gui/ModelRightMenu.cc : https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d3b06088be22a15a25025a952414bffb8ff6aa2b/gazebo/gui/ModelRightMenu.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12880/multple-appywrenchdialog,-storage-data-structure/) by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

All the link names get stored in [`gazebo::gui::ApplyWrenchDialog::linksComboBox`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d3b06088be22a15a25025a952414bffb8ff6aa2b/gazebo/gui/ApplyWrenchDialogPrivate.hh?fileviewer=file-view-default#ApplyWrenchDialogPrivate.hh-48). See the [implementation](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d3b06088be22a15a25025a952414bffb8ff6aa2b/gazebo/gui/ApplyWrenchDialog.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default) for details.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1